# problem with creating child processes in xcode

Tags: xcode, fork, process, pid

I am trying to write and debug a code in Xcode where I create several processes (which represent nodes in a network) and where these processes have to use IPC's to communicate. at first I was getting an error in my msgctl, I was trying to debug using `fprintf` to a file, when it stoped creating child processes all together, I wrote a `printf` in the form

```
pid[0]=fork();
if(pid[0]==0) {
    printf("chicken");
}
```

but nothing prints, so I am assuming that no child process is created... anybody know what I should do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to flush stdout, like this

```
printf("chicken");
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this

```
pid[0]=fork();

if(pid[0]==0)
    printf("chicken");

else if (pid[0] == -1)
    perror("fork");
```

This will print a message which will tell you where the problem is if fork didn't work. If it won't print error message fork worked correctly and you should flush(stdout) as mentioned by neoneye.